# DCHP enabled on router and on my virtual server

Tags: dhcp

I am wondering if there is any problem using dhcp on my router as well  on my VM server 2008R2 machine. Can any interference occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when clients send a request to get an IP address, the request is broadcast to the network. The DHCP-server which responds the fastest wins the game. This may lead to clients getting their addresses from two different servers, and result in conflicting addresses or settings.

Having multiple independent DHCP servers is a bad idea.